# TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to datetime.date

Tags: python, datetime

I have the following code

```
minDate = date(9999, 12, 31)
start = event.get('dtstart').dt
if isinstance(start, datetime.datetime):
        newStart = start.date()
else:
   newStart = start
if(newStart < minDate):
        minDate = start
```

why am I getting this error as I have converted to date on both ends of the comparison

Comment: It works for me if I use `datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 31)` for the value of start.  If you print out the value of `start`, what does it show? What version of Python are you using? What do your import statements look like?

Answer (score 0):

They are not the same type. From [Docs:](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/datetime.html)

> class datetime.date
>   - An idealized naive date, assuming the current Gregorian calendar always was, and always will be, in effect. Attributes: year, month, and day.
>
> class datetime.datetime
>   - A combination of a date and a time. Attributes: year, month, day, hour, minute, second, microsecond, and tzinfo

You will need to mitigate the comparison here:
`if(newStart < minDate):`

*Where* `minDate` is `date` type and `newStart` is `dateTime`